# wp cli media commands not working

Tags: media-library, wp-cli

I am trying to bulk update media file captions through WP CLI so i can attribute image creators.

My command is as follows:

```
wp media list --date="2022-02-24" --format=ids | xargs -n 1 wp media meta update {} _wp_attachment_image_alt "&lt;a href='https://www.freepik.com/'&gt;Image by pch.vector on Freepik&lt;/a&gt;"
```

I get these errors:

Error: 'list' is not a registered subcommand of 'media'. See 'wp help media' for available subcommands.
Error: 'meta' is not a registered subcommand of 'media'. See 'wp help media' for available subcommands

I have the latest version, 2.7.1

On the WP CLI documentation, it lists media subcommands. There doesn't seem to be any subcommands for updating media meta.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/

Does this mean there isnt a capability of updating media meta through wp cli?

Answer (score 3):

Media is the post type (`post_type="attachment"`), so most operations are done with `wp post` command.

By default, `wp post` manage blog posts (`post_type="post"`),
therefore by fetching post IDs you must add `--post_type=attachment` indicating the type of posts.
And to update media meta you should use `wp post meta update <id> <key> <value>`

Your entire command could look like this:

```
wp post list --date="2022-02-24" --format=ids --post_type=attachment | xargs -n 1 -I % wp post meta update % _wp_attachment_image_alt "{some meta value}"
```